# A lot of errors while reinstalling MongoDB

Tags: package-management, mysql, mongodb, regex, purge

I can't use MongoDB so I need to uninstall, but when I try to reinstall it, the program shows me a lot of errors in MongoDB, MySQL and also in dpkg.

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
Reading package lists... Done
Building the dependency tree       
Reading status information... Done
Note : selection of mongodb-org-unstable-tools for the regular expression "mongodb-org*".
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-mongos pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-tools pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-unstable-database-tools-extra pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-unstable-server pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-unstable-shell pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-shell pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-unstable-mongos pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-database-tools-extra pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-unstable pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-tools-unstable pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Note : sélection de mongodb-org-server pour l'expression rationnelle « mongodb-org* »
Le paquet « mongodb-org-unstable » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Le paquet « mongodb-org-unstable-mongos » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Le paquet « mongodb-org-unstable-server » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Le paquet « mongodb-org-unstable-shell » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Le paquet « mongodb-org-unstable-tools » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Le paquet « mongodb-org-unstable-database-tools-extra » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Le paquet « mongodb-org-tools-unstable » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Please use "sudo apt autoremove" to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED :
  mongodb-org* mongodb-org-database-tools-extra* mongodb-org-server* mongodb-org-shell* mongodb-org-tools*
The following selected packages will be changed:
  mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
0 updated, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not updated.
4 partially installed or removed.
After this operation, 53.5 MB of disk space will be freed.
Would you like to continue? Y/n] Y
E: The dpkg --set-selections sub-process returned an error code
E: Couldn't clean the currently selected dpkg states
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! To better understand how to write a good question and get relevant answers, please read [Welcome Tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and [How ask a good question](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) articles.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you purged a lot of packages using a command that contains a powerful regular expression?